# visual studio code でphp が使えない。

Tags: php, vscode

visual studio code でphpのファイルを作ったのですが、`PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting`と表示されました。

[Visual Studio Codeを使ったPHPの開発環境の構築 (Windows, Mac)](https://www.sumirelab.com/docs/tech/php/visual-studio-code%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9Fphp%E3%81%AE%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%AE%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89/)

このサイトの通りに設定を行っていたら、Pathの設定のところで躓きました。
説明すると、`"php.validate.enable": true,`のところにPathを入力できません。
どうすればいいですか。

Answer (score 2):

参考にされたページで設定しているのは、PHPの文法チェックやコード補完をVisual Studio Codeから呼び出すための設定です。
Visual Studio Codeは単なるソースコードエディタなので、PATHの設定をする(=実際にPHPを実行できるようにする)には「**PHPの実行環境**」が必要になります。
(単にコードを記述するだけであればPHPは不要です)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。色々調べてみた結果、php 本体をインストールしてシステムの環境変数から設定しました。これで、動くんですかね？

Comment: あと、もう一つ問題が出てきました。php ファイルをInternet explore で表示しようとしたら、ダウンロードの表示と追跡というのが出てきて、開けません。どうしたらいいですか？ (ちなみにインターネットオプションから詳細設定のリセットも行いましたが、治りませんでした)

Comment: 「動くんですかね？」はご自身で確認してください。 / 「開けません」は単にエディタで開ければいいのであれば関連付けを行ってください。ブラウザから開いてPHPを**動作**させるのであれば、webサーバのインストールや設定も必要になってきます。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます!!！